# python flask thread is always running, can't stop

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I use flask as http server, for Multi-threaded support, I set `threaded=True`
  The **Call Stack** shows every thread is running and not cancel when function finished.
[image]

And the memory has been growing.
[image]

Comment: Off: all I can see is a directory traversal vulnerability in the `staticFile` function. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.send_file

Comment: I update code just return 'hello', but same proplem.

Answer (score 0):

I use tornado framework solved it.